# Override Omnifaces Validation Message with JSF message-bundle?

Tags: validation, jsf, omnifaces, message-bundle

Is it possible to override the default omnifaces validation messages with a jsf message-bundle?

my message-bundle:

```
javax.faces.converter.DateTimeConverter.DATE={2}: ''{0}'' could not be understood as a date.
javax.faces.converter.DateTimeConverter.DATE_detail=Invalid date format.
javax.faces.validator.LengthValidator.MINIMUM=Minimum length of ''{0}'' is required.

org.omnifaces.component.validator.ValidateUnique=1. my validateUnique omnifaces msg, {0}
org.omnifaces.component.validator.ValidateUnique.DEFAULT_MESSAGE=2. my validateUnique omnifaces msg, {0}
```

i know there is an 'message' attribute but it would be nice to have all message at one place.

many thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is currently not supported by OmniFaces validator components. As you can see in the [source code](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/blob/master/src/org/omnifaces/component/validator/ValidateMultipleFields.java#L282) of `ValidateMultipleFields#showMessage()`, it's nowhere obtaining the default message from the message bundle as identified by [`Application#getMessageBundle()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/application/Application.html#getMessageBundle%28%29).

I reported [an issue](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/issues/39) so that the OmniFaces guys are noticed about it and may implement it for the next version. In the meanwhile your best bet is to keep using the `message` attribute. You can if necessary refactor the code duplication into a custom tagfile.

Comment: Thank you, is there a way to get a notification when Omnifaces will have implemented it? Would you be so kind roughly outline, to do it by myself?

Comment: Click the issue link and either press the subscribe button, or post a comment which will autosubscribe you.